# Solving $T(n) = 2T(\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor) + n$ with substitution method

Tags: recurrence-relation

The book I took this example from (*Introduction to Algorithms, CLRS*) wants to prove that the recurrence relation

$$T(n) = 2T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor)+n$$

is
$O(n\lg n)$ using the so-called substitution method.
When proving the inductive step, they use the strong mathematical induction, so they assume that

$$\forall m : m < n, T(m) = O(m \lg m)$$

In particular, when $m=\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ we have that

$$T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) \leq c\lfloor n/2 \rfloor \lg(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) $$

Substituting into the recurrence yields

$$T(n) \leq 2 (c\lfloor n/2 \rfloor \lg(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor)) + n $$

So they multiplied by 2 both sides, but I do not understand why there's "$+n$" at the end. Of course it comes from the recurrence relation, but I don't understand why they do that. Shouldn't they just prove that $T(n) \leq c\lfloor n/2 \rfloor \lg(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They didn't "multiply by 2 both sides". Rather, they substituted the bound they have on $T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor)$ in the recurrence relation:
\begin{align}
T(n) &\stackrel{(\dagger)}= 2T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) + n \\ &\stackrel{(\ddagger)}\leq 2c\lfloor n/2 \rfloor \lg \lfloor n/2 \rfloor + n
\end{align}
Here $(\dagger)$ is the recurrence relation, and $(\ddagger)$ is the result of substituting the induction hypothesis. In order to complete the proof of the inductive step, we need to show the following inequality $(\ast)$:
$$
2c \lfloor n/2 \rfloor \lg \lfloor n/2 \rfloor + n \stackrel{(\ast)}\leq cn\lg n
$$
In order to prove $(\ast)$, we argue as follows:
$$
2c \lfloor n/2 \rfloor \lg \lfloor n/2 \rfloor \leq 2c(n/2) \lg(n/2) + n = cn(\lg n - 1) + n = cn\lg n + (c-1)n,
$$
which is at most $cn\lg n$ as long as $c \geq 1$.

(For the proof to work, we also need the induction basis, which might require larger $c$. Note that the basis here is $n=2,3$, since $c1\lg 1 = 0$ is probably not a bound on $T(1)$.)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer and for have formatted my question better. I've got just another question: what if we did the way I asked in the question? Multiplying by 2 both sides of $T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) \leq c\lfloor n/2 \rfloor \lg(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor)$ and figuring out $T(n) \leq cn*lgn$. Would have that been a valid proof?

Comment: No. If you multiply by 2, you get $2T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) \leq 2c\lfloor n/2 \rfloor \lg \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$. This is not enough on its own to deduce anything about $T(n)$. You need to connect $T(n)$ to $T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor)$ via the recurrence.

Comment: Make sure that you understand how a proof by induction works.

Answer (score 3):

If we multiply the left-hand side $T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor)$ by $2$, we get $2T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor)$, not $T(n)$.

Let $P(n)$ be a propositional function. To prove that $P(n)$ is true for all $n \ge 1$, you can (sometimes) use the principle of strong induction, which states that it suffices to prove that $P(1)$ is true, and that for all $n \ge 2$, $P(n)$ is true whenever $P(1),P(2),...,P(n-1)$ is true. This assumption that each of $P(1),P(2),\ldots,P(n-1)$ is true is called the inductive hypothesis. In particular, by the inductive hypothesis, we have that $P(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor)$ is true.

In your example, $P(n)$ is the propositional function $T(n) \le c n \log n$, which you want to prove is true for all sufficiently large $n$.  Of course, you can also assume that $T(n) = 2 T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) + n$, since you are given in the problem statement that this equation holds for all $n$. In the right hand side of this equation, there is a term $T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor)$, for which you can substitute an upper bound of $c \lfloor n/2 \rfloor \log \lfloor n/2 \rfloor)$ because $P(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor)$ is true by the inductive hypothesis.

In other words, you can assume $T(n)=2T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor)+n$ and $T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) \le c \lfloor n/2 \rfloor \log \lfloor n/2 \rfloor)$, and you try to show that $T(n) \le c n \log n$.